# Angular ng-if OR condition

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs, i would like to enable a submit button if i choose a city OR if i type a car plate number.

My code is :

`ng-disabled="data.city.length<=0 || data.plateNumber.length<=0"`

But this condition acts like an AND, the submit button is enabled only if both two conditions are fullfilled.

I do expect this behaviour: 
The submit button enabled if i choose city field only 
OR 
If i choose plate number field only 
OR
If i choose both city and plate number fields

Thank´s in advance

Comment: Confusing negatives here. You want the button disabled, surely, if both the `city.length` is `0` *and* the `plateNumber.length` is `0`?

Comment: Using AND it work´s now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a logical problem, Re-phrasing your desired behaviour "Button should be disabled only when both city and plate number fields are empty". This translates to

```
ng-disabled="data.city.length<=0 && data.plateNumber.length<=0"
```

Answer (score 2):

You're telling angular to disable the button "If data.city is length 0 or data.platenumber is length 0". Which means it'll be disabled even if you put something into data.city, because data.platenumber is still empty.

You're looking for AND (&&), not OR (||).

Comment: could not see it was an AND condition, thank you now it is working.